# Where can I find a complete list of Angular structural directives?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Where can I find a complete list of Angular structural directives?  I'm aware of these:

```
*ngFor
*ngIf
*ngSwitchCase
*ngSwitchDefault
*ngSwitch
*ngTemplateOutput
```

Are there any others?  I figure that there must be a complete list somewhere, but so far, I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Here https://angular.io/api/common#directives

Comment: Thanks, but that's a list of all directives.  I'm trying to get a list of just structural directives.

Answer (score 0):

Directive is a directive. Here are some information regarding them.

**[Structural Directives](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#what-are-structural-directives)**

> Structural directives are responsible for HTML layout. They shape or reshape the DOM's structure, typically by adding, removing, or manipulating elements.
>
> As with other directives, you apply a structural directive to a host element. The directive then does whatever it's supposed to do with that host element and its descendants.
>
> Structural directives are easy to recognise. An asterisk (*) precedes the directive attribute name as in this example.

**[The asterisk (*) prefix](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-asterisk--prefix)**

> Surely you noticed the asterisk (*) prefix to the directive name and wondered why it is necessary and what it does.
>
> Here is *ngIf displaying the hero's name if hero exists.

```
<div *ngIf="hero" class="name">{{hero.name}}</div>
```

> The asterisk is "syntactic sugar" for something a bit more complicated. Internally, Angular translates the *ngIf attribute into a  element, wrapped around the host element, like this.

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="hero">
  <div class="name">{{hero.name}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

- The *ngIf directive moved to the  element where it
  became a property binding,[ngIf].
- The rest of the , including its class attribute, moved inside the  element.

**When we prepend a directive with * we are telling it to use the element it’s attached to as the template.**

**[Built-in structural directives](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#built-in-structural-directives)**

> Structural directives are responsible for HTML layout. They shape or reshape the DOM's structure, typically by adding, removing, and manipulating the host elements to which they are attached.
>
> This section is an introduction to the common built-in structural directives:

- NgIf—conditionally creates or destroys subviews from the template.
- NgFor—repeat a node for each item in a list.
- NgSwitch—a set of directives that switch among alternative views.

**All list of structural directives in [Angular Common](https://angular.io/api/common#directives) package are**

- NgComponentOutlet
- NgForOf
- NgIf
- NgSwitchCase
- NgSwitchDefault
- NgTemplateOutlet